# Good way to ensure data is ready to be queried while Glue partition is created?

Tags: aws-glue-data-catalog

We have queries that run on a schedule every several minutes that join a few different glue tables (via Athena) before coming up with some results. For the table in question, we have Glue Crawlers set up and partitions based on snapshot_date and a couple other columns.

In the query, we grab the latest snapshot_date and use only data from that snapshot_date for the query. The data in S3 gets updated and put into the right folder a few times a day, but it looks like sometimes, if we try to query the data right as the data in S3 is getting updated, we end up with empty results due to the query trying to access the new snapshot_date partition while Glue is still getting the data set up(?)

Is there a built-in way to ensure that our glue partitions are ready before we start querying them? So far, we considered building in artificial time "buffers" in our query around when we expect the snapshot_date partition data to be written and the glue update to be complete, but I'm aware that that's really brittle and depends on the exact timing.